# What circuit should I study, to learn all the details of the 555 timer?

Tags: 555

I understand OHM's Law, and have a conceptual grasp of RCL circuits, but am a little weak on the math. I am good at math, even a little calculus, just weak on RCL math.

I am trying to understand the 555 timer. I have seen various 'cookbooks', but it's like someone is trying to teach me about internal combustion engines, when I don't understand campfires.

The monostable multivibrator is generally presented first, but it does not utilize each pin individually, as some are tied together. I am trying to get a snapshot of all features offered by the 555.

I have figured out that, if I have a push button providing the trigger signal, I would want to have a capacitor in series, to limit the pulse width. Regarding the value of the capacitor, I suppose I could use trial and error.

I have a breadboard and some components on order. I'm just trying to read up a little bit in the meantime.

Comment: Have you read the [555 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf)? What specifically don't you understand about it?

Comment: If you Google "555 tutorial" you'll find just exactly what you're looking for, thousands of times over.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html) or [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yej4X5wyugE).

Comment: This falls into the category of "what textbook should I read?"-type questions for me.

Comment: You may also find this of interest: http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2014/555v2/ (a 555 made from discretes).

Comment: You'll find a [555 reading list here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/555/info).

Answer (score 1):

To get a better overview of all the features of an IC, you're usually going to want to read [the product datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM555.pdf), rather than expecting any example circuit to demonstrate all of its capabilities.

If/when the datasheet gets a bit too deep for you, it may help (when using as popular a component as the 555) to read [The Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC) for an easier-to-understand overview.

Finally, if you still want/need some (more) example circuits to follow, or want more information/calculators/etc for using the chip, you could always read the [Entire Website Dedicated to 555 Timers](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com).

Comment: Excellent website; definitely a keeper! :)

Answer (score 1):

Study resistors, transistors, voltage comparators, voltage dividers, R-S latches(flip-flops), and [**this data sheet**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf).

There's an error or two in its graphics, and if you can find it/them you'll be well on your way to understanding the 555. ;)

You might also want to go to the source and study Hans Kamenzind's book, free, from:

http://www.designinganalogchips.com/

Click on "Download Book" at the end of the third paragraph.